# Strange error of dimensionally on the EditText after disabling the standard Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

in my app I have disabled the standard Android keyboard for each EditText with

```
myEditText.setInputType(0);
```

but now when I use the instruction:

```
myEditText.setText("string");
```

the sizes of my EditText does not fit to the size of the text you entered; so the text is not displaying in whole.

How can I fix this?

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="305dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="DECIMAL:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
         >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml file containing editText

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable editText then I recommend to use editText.setEnabled(false). Hiding keyboard is not the right solution until you really need it. But if you have disabled edittext then keyboard will not appear even if you focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think problem is because of keyboard. One thing I observed in your code is, you are setting `ems` for `editText`. I think because of `ems`, editText size is constant always. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aems) link for more information.

Comment: I deleted this statement android:ems = "10" but the problem is the same

Comment: I ran your exact code as it is. Its working fine. Keyboard is not opening but whatever text u set to editText, its showing fully. Check once again. As i suggested, ems was the problem. Without that its working fine